# How to have an interactive console in VS Code for python?

Tags: python, matlab, console, visual-studio-code, interactive

In Matlab and R, I can run a code and the console/terminal of MATLAB's editor and R-Studio will expose the session to me. In a way that I can access all the variables and results of my simulations from the console. I have found some solutions online, but I am not satisfied with them or they were not clear to me. 
So here is the question:

- How can I modify VS Code so that the code which I am running will have the same session in the terminal or change it to pythons currently running session?
- ipython or jupyter seems to do this task. How can I do that in ipython/jupyter?

Let say if I have in my python p1.py the following line:

```
a=3
```

and I execute the above-mentioned line, after execution, I want to be able to input the following line in the terminal or console of VS Code and get a correct result:

```
b=a+10
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In USER SETTINGS I modified the following:

```
{
    "jupyter.appendResults": true,
    //"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Scripts\\ipython.exe",
    "[python]": {
    }
}
```

Then I added this line:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "run"
    //"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python.exe"
}
```

In the WORKSPACE SETTINGS of VS Code. After running a simple addition/subtraction test, I can access the variables in the *ipython* terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` which will send the text to a Python REPL instance. If you're after changes in the REPL to be reflected in the editor then I'm afraid that support does not exist.

Comment: Have you ever used MATLAB or R?

Comment: Yes, but the OP's request was a bit confusing to me so I tried to answer what I thought they were explicitly asking. But based on your question, Ash, I assume you took what they wanted differently. I've gone ahead and changed my answer to encompass what I thought they were after and what I suspect you're suggesting they were after.

Comment: Sorry I guess there is misunderstanding. I want to use VSCode exactly the same way I use MATLAB. This is not how VS Code works. After executing the file, your terminal is not interactive, which means the session you created to run your file is gone and all the variables, etc are cleared off of the memory. Is this clear now?